# How to take variable from function to another function

Tags: php, regex

I want to search some tag in text,  and return the variable with what I need
but, I got an error that's `Undefined variable: $s`

so I've tried to make global $s

but nothing,

my code is there

```
function xs($letter, $xs, $s) {
    $letter = preg_replace_callback(
        '/'.$xs.'/', 
        function ($match) {
            static $i;
            $i++;
            return $s;
        }, 
        $letter
    );

    return $letter;
}
```

thank you :)

Comment: `function ($match) use ($s) {`

Comment: error > PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion

Comment: Apparently either `$s` or `$xs` is an array - both need to be strings for your code to work.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo plz give me a sample code

Comment: @AligaMyway RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Your code does not make sense as you are keeping a count in variable `$i` which you are never using. What are you trying to do?

Comment: in text file, i want to change all of the words with what i want into a random string